# sam local start-api cannot be accessed from outside

Tags: lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am using aws sam local to developer few lambdas/nanoservices

I start the lambda container with:

```
sudo sam local start-api --docker-network db-pros
```

*where db-pros is the database container*

when I go to 127.0.0.1:3000/*lambda-name* everything works fine however when I try to connect from the test device (Android phone which is connected to WiFi) I cannot.

Tried to use the IP (both Ethernet and docker0) from `ifconfig` and I still can't connect.

I do not know if it's possible and if yes how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sam local start-api --host 0.0.0.0` instead.